# Two subdomains pointing to two different hosts?

Tags: dns

For example, let's say I have domain.com. Can I configure http://subdomain1.domain.com to be hosted on http://www.squarespace.com and http://subdomain2.domain.com to be hosted on http://www.discountasp.net/?

Comment: Not programming related in the least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Set the A record of subdomain1 to point to the IP of your site at squarespace.com and the A record for subdomain2 to point to the IP being hosted at discountasp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - either use a CNAME record and point it to each of those domains, or an A record for the full domain (`subdomain1.domain.com`) pointed at the IP address you need.